# Connect pentaho 9.1 to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2012, pentaho

I'm trying to connect to pentaho 9.1 to Azure SQL Server in Windows desktop Environment  and I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server' driver (jar file) is installed.
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I've already downloaded JDBC driver from Microsoft and copy mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8 to lib path or mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre11 to lib path as well. I already did copy mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64.dll to \libswt\win64.

Some idea of what should I do?

Comment: What is your java version which was use to run Pentaho9.1?   As you are using driver mssql-jdbc-9.2.0  which is support only Java 8, 11, and 15

Comment: my java version is 1.8.0_281

Answer (score 1):

I got !

just download the driver from  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

Answer's source - https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/217129-How-to-connect-PDI-with-MS-SQL-Server-2016/